# Help with Array List - PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array value like this.

My `print_r($_POST)` looks like this.
I can get the post count value too. (Here the count value is 3)

```
Array ( [tag] => Array ( [4-a] => User1 [8-a] => User2 [3-a] => User3 ))
```

Now, i want the above array values in a single string.

For ex:

```
$all_users = User1,User2,User3
```

Is this possible . Pl advice.

Haan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$all_users = implode(',',$your_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question well...

```
$array = Array ( 'tag' => Array ( '4-a' => 'User1', '8-a' => 'User2', '3-a' => 'User3' ));
$allUsers = '';
$first = true;

foreach($array['tag'] as $key=>$value) {

  if($first == false) {
    $allUsers .= ',' . $value;
  } else {
    $allUsers .= $value;
  }

  $first = false;

}

echo $allUsers;
```